# Regex that captures any text that between 2 constants

Tags: regex

I was looking for a regex that catch any text that is between 2 constants, example:

```
//==Constant1==
-Any
-Other
-Text
//==Constant2==
```

I need to catch the whole block or at least the text inside Constant1 and Constant2, I can have linebreaks, numbers, any other sign (backslashes,parhentesis,etc). I have tried with many regex as:

```
\/\/==start==(.*)\/\/==end==/s
```

but that doesnt work, any suggestion?

Comment: What is regex flavor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in most flavors

```
^//==Constant1==[\n\r]
([\s\S]+?)
^//==Constant2==
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8b2nI3/1) (and mind the `multiline` and `verbose` modifier!).

---

Broken down, it says:

```
^//==Constant1==[\n\r]  # match //==Constant1== in one line
([\s\S]+?)              # anything else lazily in between
^//==Constant2==        # up until //==Constant2== in another line
```

Depending on your flavor, you might need to escape the forward slashes to

```
^\/\/==Constant1==[\n\r]
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include the linebreaks in your regex. Try this: `\/\/==Constant1==\n(.+\n)*\/\/==Constant2==`

Tip: You can always try your regex'es here https://regex101.com/.